# Agarrar um botão no Splinter (python)

Tags: python, button

Para a maioria dos botões que tento agarrar usando o Splinter, os comandos que estão neste site (https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/finding.html) bastam.

Porém, para este botão especifico, não acho uma maneira de agarra-lo.

```
<button type="submit">Vote</button>
```

Como fazer se não consigo identificar o nome dele, ou o id?

Comment: Respondi à sua pergunta em baixo nos comentários

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como a sua pergunta mais cedo a que respondi, é possível mas em vez do metodo `find_by_value` use o `find_by_css`, que define o seletor css do elemento html:

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.visit("url aqui")
    button = browser.find_by_css('button[type="submit"]')[0] # agarramos o button seletor css
    button.click()
```

Pode também 'agarrar' pela sua tag html:

```
browser.find_by_tag('button')
```

Ou mesmo pelo texto:

```
browser.find_by_text('Vote')
```

Comment: O stackoverflow pede para não usarmos os comentários para agradecer, mas muito obrigado pela resposta das duas perguntas! Estou começando na área e cometo alguns erros bobos desses... Para completar, poderia apenas explicar rapidamente o seria o 'css' ou a 'tag', em questão do código fonte? Só pra eu não ter que continuar perguntando esse tipo de coisa.... grato!

Comment: Olá @F Navi, neste contexto css quer dizer que pode usar os seletores css para os elementos HTML, e tag é o elemento em si, que neste caso é um `button`, já na sua outra questão é `input`